# Minimization of a function with n=10^4 and n=10^5

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I have the following function to put in MATLAB and then apply Newton method to try to minimize it.

[image: function]

My problem is that I have no idea how to write the exact gradient and hessian of this function. I have written the function as a function handle but for the hessian and the gradient nothing comes to help me. Can someone help me to write them?

Comment: That _looks_ like a fairly simple function (just a polynomial over x_i's), so the gradient/Hessian should be easy to calculate using normal differential calculus?

Comment: but my problem is that i don't know how to write them in matlab code

Comment: Forgetting Matlab first, are you able to write down the math formula for gradient/Hessian first?

Comment: yes for me the gradient is : summation of x^3 + x+1 and the Hessian is : 3x^2 +1

Comment: `x^3 + x+1 = 0` admit only one solution in the real domain, so every `x_i` should have the same value and this value would be the real solution of `x^3 + x+1 = 0`.

Comment: yes i'm absolutly agree with you, but how can i write it in matlab code?